# Using django model _meta to identify tenant

Tags: django, orm

I have a need to select a particular database to service a request. The selection depends on the domain name that was hit. In other words, I need to implement multi tenancy with each tenant having a separate database.

Now, at the time of servicing the request, I get a list of all models of my app and set the _meta of the model to reflect the tenant. Like so:

```
def my_request(request):
    all_models=apps.get_app_config('MY_APP_NAME').get_models()
    for modl in all_models:
        modl._meta.app_label = tenant_id
```

I have a `db_router` configured that then uses the `tenant_id` to select a database and return that.

This is not thread safe right? Does Django create a fresh set of models, (these are classes, not object instances) for each request or is only one copy used? I understand there are better ways to solve the problem, but I wanted to know if I was correct in my assessment that the above is an error.

Comment: No, this is not thread-safe, and will most likely break parts of Django, since the `app_label` in `Model._meta` will no longer match the `app_label` in `apps`. `Model._meta.app_label` should be treated as a read-only attribute.